# How are quants able to verify whether their calculated prices are any good

Tags: option-pricing, equities, fixed-income, models

This question is related to the discussion on [Model Validation Criteria](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/176/model-validation-criteria)
However it appeard to be very high level to me and I would like to go more into detail.

Not working at a pricing desk the following has always puzzled me: 
**How are quants able to verify whether their calculated prices are any good?**
*(by "calculated prices" I mean the ones output by some model - e.g. B&S, Heston )*

One could perhaps distingusih the two:

- A priori
- A posteriori

I would assume a priory mainly consists of model choice (fitting the market data etc.) - Thus the A priori part is related to [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10300/which-interest-rate-model-for-which-product).

Alas, I am quite clueless what an a posteriori check would look like. 
What would be the benchmark one would check against ?

Comment: In a risk-neutral setting the P&L should be the definitive a posteriori verification, right?

Comment: When you say their calculated prices, you're referring to the values that are output from models (like pricing an option with BS), right, rather than the bid/ask prices quoted in the market?

Comment: correct - I will edit the questipn - this is a necessary specification :) thank you

Comment: On the sell-side, one could argue that a 'good' model is one whose a posteriori replication PNL exceeds the quoted margin, or perhaps one that allowed you to sell the deal in the first place (depending on your level of cynicism).  On the buy-side, assuming you aren't hedging, then a posteriori, the models which identify options that are mis-priced under P are the good ones.  

There's a big difference between models which are widely used, models which match the market well, and models which capture asset dynamics accurately.  http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2365294

Comment: thank you for the paper. Do you have any more references on the topic. Please write your comment as an answer. It was already a great help - I would like to upvote it and for it to be visible to other. cheers